# Scraping opensea that uses GraphQL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, post, http-status-code-403, opensea

So, I am working on a project that needs data from `opensea`. More specifically, I need the NFT offers and listings from,
[https://opensea.io/nickname808/activity?search[eventTypes][0]=OFFER_ENTERED&search[eventTypes][1]=AUCTION_CREATED](https://opensea.io/nickname808/activity?search%5BeventTypes%5D%5B0%5D=OFFER_ENTERED&search%5BeventTypes%5D%5B1%5D=AUCTION_CREATED)
and more similar pages. I looked into the Network tab, it uses `graphql` to load the data dynamically.

I tried to imitate the post request but got the `403` error in return. I have tried selenium , which gets the work done but is awfully slow.

So, any suggestions on   how can I get the data from the website faster and without getting the `403` in response.